# Bitmap (or view?) fading

Tags: java, android, bitmap

If I display a bitmap as a background, and then draw 3 other, smaller, bitmaps on top, is there a way to fade the background without affecting the other 3 bitmaps?

Basically what I want to do is to move three 'sprite buttons' and a logo image onto the screen, over the top of the game screen, and have the background fade down while the buttons are displayed. When the buttons move off, I want the background to fade back in again.

Any ideas?

Look, this is a design question initially. I need to see if it's possible before I commit.

I have a background. On this I want to show 3 'sprites'. I want to fade the background down without fading the sprites. Is this possible and, if so, how best should it be done?

Comment: An image (serie) would help understanding the problem.

Comment: Do you mean an image of my screen? Can't do that, I'm afraid, I can't let images of the game out yet.

Comment: Well... how are we supposed to help you, if we dont see what you mean?

Comment: @DerGol...lum Answer me this: I've spoken to several people about this question, everybody agrees it's a sensible and easily understood question. Why are you treating me this way? I've been coding for nearly 40 years, I have plenty of experience. I'm not a novice. Does SO not want discuss actual coding problems, or does the quality of the question matter MORE than the question itself?

Comment: Listen... nothing personal, really. But you should really read [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you want to get some help, you must provide a [Minimal, Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. Or **at least** show some picture of what you want and what you get instead. Even if you make your image/s in Gimp, it doesn't matter. We don't want to steal your graphics artwork. But show some effort! It takes nothing to say I'm an aged programmer, give me some code. Do you get the point?

Comment: I give in! It astounds me that you need a graphic to be able to understand this!

Comment: You may recall from school that `an image is worth a 1000 words`, don't you?

Comment: My mentioning my experience is down to feeling that you're treating me like a novice. There a plenty of other questions on this site with no examples, images or anything that you're after. It definitely feels like the only thing you're bothered about is the quality of the question.
if you can't picture this without needing an image to look at, then i'd question your abilities if I were you.

Comment: Is **this** the question `I have a background. On this I want to show 3 'sprites'. I want to fade the background down without fading the sprites. Is this possible and, if so, how best should it be done?`?

Comment: Then the answer is **obviously, yes**. But some little trickery is needed.

Comment: Well, OBVIOUSLY that's the question! It's properly constructed, like a question should be...
(It's actually asked twice...)

Comment: Well, maybe you were too prolax (does such a word exist in English?  and does it mean what I do mean?). Prolix?

Comment: Actually it's not even real trickery you need. Just a deeper knowledge of how graphics works in Android. Imagine it's a **2 independent layers** stack. One is the `image` and the other one is the `background`. So work, at least, ImageViews and ImageButtons. I think the former ones are what you are actually using (WILD GUESS, since I sill see no code).

Comment: By the way, the word was "wordy", or... "verbose" (oh, yes! like the compiler mode!).

Comment: There's no code to show because I haven't written it yet. Like I said, this is a design question. If it can be done easily, I'll code something.

Comment: Well, that was about the sprites themselves. Now, you asked for a fading background. Let's say you have 3 spaceships (or UFOs, letters, pac-men, whatever) floating on a starry background. Now you want the starry background to fade away to another color. Simply this background could be another ImageView placed inbetween the sprites and the container layout's background picture (or color), into which you want to blend the stars. This is simply achieved in a loop where you set the Alpha of your stars (picture) progressively to 0.

Comment: I hope this was somehow more helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Der Gol...lum

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the background image will fade and the other 3 will not, is there a reason why they are in the same "container".

If not, then consider having only the background being altered, and the other three images isolated from the altering code.

If they must be drawned together or inside the same bitmap, consider having regions not to alter inside the bitmap, perhaps by clustering the image, and placing identifiers on those regions with a boolean (such as "isAlterable"), then only calling the fade on isAlterable clusters

Comment: If I use canvas.DrawBitmap, then there would be 4 independent bitmaps being displayed, is that right?

Comment: If you loaded 4 canvas, yes, if you loaded one canvas, then altered it, no.